# What should be the target of a Javascript keypress event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'm writing a userscript for a site that accepts input from the keyboard to expand the next article in a list of articles. The "expand article" action is performed when the <kbd>j</kbd> key is pressed and an input field does not have focus.

I've found the following working jQuery command to generate the keypress event:

`$('.some_element').trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 74}))`

What element can I replace the `'.some_element'` selector with to make the website recognize my keystroke? I've tried `window`, `document`, and `'body'`, but none of these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made need the `which` property as well

```
$(document).trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 74, which: 74}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).trigger... Also make sure you have if condition for no input focused.

Comment: "_I've tried window, document, and body, but none of these work._"

Comment: Try this `$(document).on('keydown', function(e){ // your code })`
here's a codepen https://codepen.io/simranz/pen/NBzXmX

Comment: It's a userscript, so I don't have access the code that handles the keypress. I just need to send the keypress with javascript.

Comment: Well, I haven't used userscript. But if you can trigger event on an element in DOM then theoretically you can do that on `$('body')` as well.